# Magento Tax Calculation is wrong

Tags: magento2.3.3, tax-calculation

My Magento 2.3.3 Store is not calculating the VAT correctly.
I need to charge 19% VAT which is INCLUDED in the price.

But in the cart, the VAT calculation is wrong. Magento only calculates with 16% and I don't know why.

Here are my Settings:

> https://prntscr.com/qjwesh
>
> https://prntscr.com/qjweu2
>
> https://prntscr.com/qjwevi
>
> https://prntscr.com/qjwexf
>
> https://prntscr.com/qjwf21

How can I fix this?